# Installation discs

Tags: software-installation, dvd, disk, system

May I create my own installation DVD from your site?  If so, are there detailed, step-by-step tutorials that include ALL necessary steps, including "...which torrent; DVD writer, etc." for a Windows 7 user (and not even very swift user, at that.)

Comment: This site is community-run site devoted to answering specific questions relating to Ubuntu. If you would like, you can reformat your question to better suit a specific purpose, such as "How to do X". However before you do this, I would recommend using the [search](http://askubuntu.com/search) function to see if someone has already answered your question. If you would like to learn more about how this site can help you, try taking the [Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) or check out the [Help Center](http://askubuntu.com/help).

Comment: For Windows questions, try http://superuser.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu). Read the answer by penreturns.

Answer (score 1):

Go here and download recommended release/flavour:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Underneath download links are links to instructions for switching, burning DVDs, etc.

Or you can follow Microsoft's instructions to burn the ISO to a DVD from here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file